# Finding aspect ratio of data in 3d matrices

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matrix `C` that shows concentration of a population at each point in 3D space. So each element of the matrix has a value between 0 and 1. The data is nonzero inside an ellipsoid and outside the ellipsoid it is zero. The boundary of the ellipsoid is defined as the elements which are equal to 0.5.

I have been trying to find the aspect ratio of the ellipsoid, but no success yet. Could someone please help me?

I tried

> [C3,h3] = contour3(C(:,:,:),[0.5 0.5 0.5],'-g');

to get the boundary of the data, but not sure what to do next.

Comment: The line of code you show does nothing but plot the ellipsoid. How do you define the ellispoid's aspect ratio? That should give you a good starting point to start coding, given you can implement your definition.

Comment: elipsoid's aspect ratio is the ratio between smallest diameter to the largest diameter of the ellipsoid. @Adriaan

Comment: @Adriaan I think h3 gives the boundary of the ellipsoid. So I need to find the aspect ratio then. But I do not know how to do this.

Comment: You'll need to find the major axes of your ellipsoid. Take a look at `pca` for that. Then it's a simle matter of dividing the smallest by the largest found value (out of 3, given you have 3 axes)

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the [minimum volume ellipsoid](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9542-minimum-volume-enclosing-ellipsoid), as `|(X - c)'*A*(X-c)|=1`, then you use the singular values of A to find the aspect ratio.

Since your matrix is a volume what you have to do is to take only the points at the boundary of the matrix, otherwise the problem will be too complex.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: The link finds the aspect ratio for a 2d data set. My data is 3d